# R [glmnet]: Error: Matrices must have same number of columns in rbind2

Tags: r, glmnet

Running R cv.glmnet function from glmnet package, I got the following error:

```
Error: Matrices must have same number of columns in rbind2(.Call(dense_to_Csparse, x), y)
```

I routinely use the cv.glmnet function, but I've never had this error message before. I tried to figure out what it was but could't come up with a good answer. I have no idea what it means and where to begin to solve this problem.

Here's a quick rundown of the data.
I am trying to fit a ridge logistic regression. The dimension of the data (training) is 152 x 23. The outcome is binary, of course, with 141 0's and 11 1's. A summary of 22 predictors is shown below.

```
> summary(train)
 outcome A     B       C       D      E      F       G      H       I       J       K      
 0:141   0:4   0:139   0:120   0:63   0:63   0:138   0:71   0:120   0:129   0:125   0:149  
 1: 11   1:4   1: 13   1: 32   1:89   1:89   1: 14   1:81   1: 32   1: 23   1: 27   1:  3  
 L       M      N       O       P       Q       R      S      T       U       V     
 0:139   0:65   0:133   0:138   0:136   0:108   0:76   0:68   0:116   0:138   0:71  
 1: 13   1:87   1: 19   1: 14   1: 16   1: 44   1:76   1:84   1: 36   1: 14   1:81
```

Code below contains the reproducible dataset and cv.glmnet function that I used.

Any suggestions and thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
train <- structure(list(outcome = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), A = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                      2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               B = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               C = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               D = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               E = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               F = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               G = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               H = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               I = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               J = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               K = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               L = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               M = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               N = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               O = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               P = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               Q = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               R = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               S = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               T = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               U = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               V = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
                                                                                                                22L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
                                                                                                                37L, 40L, 41L, 43L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 54L, 55L, 57L, 
                                                                                                                58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 63L, 67L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
                                                                                                                77L, 78L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 90L, 92L, 95L, 
                                                                                                                96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 101L, 102L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 109L, 
                                                                                                                110L, 112L, 113L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 120L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 
                                                                                                                127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 136L, 137L, 139L, 140L, 
                                                                                                                141L, 143L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 157L, 
                                                                                                                159L, 161L, 163L, 164L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 170L, 172L, 175L, 176L, 
                                                                                                                177L, 179L, 181L, 183L, 184L, 186L, 187L, 189L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 
                                                                                                                196L, 199L, 200L, 202L, 204L, 208L, 209L, 211L, 212L, 214L, 215L, 
                                                                                                                216L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 227L), class = "data.frame")

set.seed(12345)
  ridge.fit <- cv.glmnet(data.matrix(train[,-1]),
                         train[,1], 
                         family         = "binomial",
                         penalty.factor = c(rep(0, 16), rep(1, 6)),
                         nfolds         = nrow(train),
                         grouped        = FALSE,
                         type.measure   = "class",
                         alpha          = 0,
                         standardize    = FALSE)
```

Comment: You can't fit a model with more non-zero coefficients than negative examples + 1. You can get the model to work by allowing more penalty.factors to be non-zero.

Comment: @AriAnisfeld Hi Ari, Thanks for the comment. I don't think I understood thoroughly though. Could you please explain a bit more in detail? A simple example would be great.

Comment: For example, if you run the model with `penalty.factor = rep(1, 22)` the cross validation procedure works. Similarly, It seems like the model fits if you have `penalty.factor = c(rep(0, 10), rep(1, 12))`. My earlier comment appears to be wrong though; when I run the model with `penalty.factor = c(rep(0, 11), rep(1,11))`  so there are 11 or more unrestricted coefficients the model fails to converge.

Comment: @AriAnisfeld I understood. Penalty factor was causing a problem. Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!!! I sincerely appreciate it.